# disable validation of errorprovider when click cancel button

Tags: winforms, errorprovider

is there a way to disable the validation of errorprovider elegantly when click cancel button to dismiss a winform? 
The validation always happens when the textbox lose focus, and i don't wanna it to validate when the user click cancel button, it is just a little bit silly to validate when the user clicking cancel.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

after googling, found the answer, just set CauseValidation property of the cancel button to false. that's it.

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into this myself and setting `CauseValidation = false` is only a partial solution.

When you set the `Form.CancelButton` to the cancel button, the Escape key is supposed to invoke that button. It does, however, validation still runs in response to the Escape key, even though we set `CauseValidation = false`.

To fix it, add the following hack:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    // Although we set CausesValidation = false for the Cancel button,
    //  the Escape key fails to cancel due to validation failure. The
    //  Form.CancelButton property should invoke the validation-free
    //  cancel button, but doesn't. Force the issue here.
    if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```