# errorprovider won't let me exit the form until I clear the error

Tags: c#, winforms

Why is it when I first come to my window which is a form with a user control and combo box set to blank. I can click Cancel without any problem and window closes. However, if I touch the combo box and then leave it blank and I try to click Cancel the cancel event doesn't fire?

Comment: [Take a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995213/disable-validation-of-errorprovider-when-click-cancel-button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use container.AutoValidate = .EnableAllowFocusChange

Answer (score 5):

All you actually need is

```
 e.Cancel = False;
```

in your FormClosing event.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues, but then I solved it by

- Setting the CausesValidation property of the button to False.
- Re-setting all the controls on the form.
- Closing the Form.

  ```
  while (Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            Controls[0].Dispose();
        }
        this.Close();
  ```

I added this code to the Button_Click() event as well as the From_Closing event.
Regards,
Kshitij Thube

Answer (score 0):

Rod's answer leads to the solution.
If the forms (container of the error-provider) `AutoValidate`-property is set to `EnableAllowFoucsChange`, button events are handled and in the `Click`-Event now it is possible to check if the form has invalid children:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If Not ValidateChildren() Then Exit Sub
End sub
```